# is it possible to use MPMusicPlayerController with simpleAudio Engine simultaneously in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have a application which have a music selection layer- an option for selecting background mp3  music reside in resource folder and an option for selecting music from ipod. Now problem is that when i select music from ipod and then after game over if i start a new game and select background music from resource music it does not start.it gives the following log message-

> 2011-01-08 22:45:10.085
> TapTapBugs[2247:307]
> Denshion::CDLongAudioSource - Loading
> new audio source backGroundMusic1.mp3
>
> 2011-01-08 22:45:10.360
> TapTapBugs[2247:307]
> Denshion::CDAudioManager - preload
> background music aborted because audio
> is not exclusive
>
> 22:45:10.416 TapTapBugs[2247:307]
> Denshion::CDAudioManager - play bgm
> aborted because audio is not exclusive
> or sound is muted

Now my question- **is it possible to use - MPMusicPlayerController with simpleAudio Engine in same application or not.And if possible how to do it??**

Comment: I am working on ios 4.1.

Comment: No, i haven't solved it. So i made a choice between them, like when game opened if you select game music,you can't use iPod music or When you select iPod music you can't use game music until you quit the game.

Comment: okay thanks for that...but the problem i am facing is every time the game music overrides the iPod music. i want that when i start my game, if iPod music is running then there should be no background music. could u help in this matter?